# JavaFX: Laying out Nodes in a Row

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Given following layout:

[image]

In some cases *Field 2* (and the corresponding `Label`above) are invisible and *Field 3* and *Field 4* shall be moved left accordingly.

My first attempt was to place the elements in a `Pane` (as I did as well for the screenshot in this example) and recalculate the exact positions of all elements if one is set invisible. This solution is working but it needs lot of maintenance if the element, their sizes or order changes.

In the course of discussing another problem I got the idea to use a `HBox` to place the fields in it, which would give me auto-spacing.

But using a `HBox` does not do the trick, because:

1. As far as I see in a `HBox` the labels cannot be set above the elements.
2. If I set an element invisible the other elements won't move left.

Any ideas how to archive my desired behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Put each `Label` with `ComboBox/Label` into `VBox`. Then add/remove them from `HBox` depending on your requirements. Another solution is to put everything into `GridPane` and add/remove columns.

Comment: If you prefer to use `setVisible()` instead of adding and removing the `VBox`, just bind the `VBox`'s `managedProperty()` to its `visibleProperty()`.

Answer (score 2):

Making a `Node` invisible does not remove it from the layout. Removing a node from a parent layout is done by

1. removing a `Node` from the child list of the parent *or*
2. setting the `managed` property of the node to `false`.

Example showing/hiding a node using the `managed` property:

```
public static void toggleVisibility(Node node) {
    boolean newValue = !node.isVisible();
    node.setVisible(newValue);

    // invisible nodes should not be taken into account for HBox layout
    node.setManaged(newValue);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.RED.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5));
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.GREEN.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5));
    Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.BLUE.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5));
    HBox hbox = new HBox(rect1, rect2, rect3);

    Scene scene = new Scene(hbox);
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        toggleVisibility(rect2);
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```